# Subversion: record-only merge

Tags: svn, merge

I encounter some strange for me difference between merge and record-only merge...

```
svn merge "^/branches/release-8.0" .
--- Merging r22415 through r22446 into '.':
 G   .
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r22415 through r22446 into '.':
 U   .

... revert ...

svn merge --record-only "^/branches/release-8.0" .
--- Merging r2 through r22414 into '.':
 G   .
--- Merging r22415 through r22446 into '.':
 G   .
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r22415 through r22446 into '.':
 G   .
```

in second case performed merging r2 through r22414, which is not expected. It take ~5 minutes, so first I think it is hung. (First merge take 2-3 seconds.)

Merge info:

```
trunk:
svn pg svn:mergeinfo
<empty>

branch
svn pg svn:mergeinfo
/trunk:22415-22439
```

I do not known which additional information can help, because on test example it is not reproduced.

Subversion 1.7:

```
svn, version 1.7.10 (r1485443)
   compiled Jun  1 2013, 09:36:13
```

May be some guesses ?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the previous merge was on r22414, so your mergeinfo contains information about it. Try this to see if you have it: 
svn propget svn:mergeinfo

1) it's MERGING changes starting from the latest merge. Thus, r22415 through r22446 - Note, that this is an actual merge

2) it's RECORDING (--record-only) merging info into your working folder. Due to the absence of info about the merge before r22414, it's adding it to your mergeinfo. That's the reason it's taking long. - Note, that this is not a merge, just a record into your working folder.